# MediaStreamSource play stream from UDP

Tags: .net, sockets, windows-phone-8, udp

I want recive stream which is voice and play it. So I configure socket and receveing works fine, but I have problem with correct playing my stream. I'm perfectly sure that my incoming stream is ok. Tested on android and iOS.

Receveing stream

```
private async void SocketOnMessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            var result = args.GetDataStream();
            var resultStream = result.AsStreamForRead(4096);

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(resultStream))
            {
                var audio = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("audio.length "+audio.Length);
                    AudioSteam.AddBytes(audio);

                });
            }
        }
```

For playing sound I modify a little bit code form this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852599.aspx)

My modified code

```
protected override void GetSampleAsync(MediaStreamType mediaStreamType)
        {

            // Send out the sample
            ReportGetSampleCompleted(new MediaStreamSample(mediaStreamDescription,
                                                            memoryStream,
                                                            0,
                                                            BufferSize,
                                                            timestamp,
                                                            mediaSampleAttributes));
            // Prepare for next sample
            timestamp += BufferSamples * 10000000L / sampleRate;

        }
```

And add one method for stream provide

```
 public void AddBytes(string bytes) {            
            var audioBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bytes);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            memoryStream.Write(audioBytes,0,audioBytes.Length);

        }
```

What's wrong? In which part, receiving or playing, I mess up?

UPDATE:
It looks like ui thread isn't the best way to read continuous sound. So I got rid of it and now receiving method look like this

```
private void SocketOnMessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            var result = args.GetDataStream();
            var resultStream = result.AsStreamForRead(4096);

            var reader = new StreamReader(resultStream);
                var audio = reader.ReadToEnd();
                AudioSteam.AddBytes(audio);

        }
```

What's more it's could be bad setting for MediaSourceStream. ATM it's set like this

```
            const int ChannelCount = 1;
            const int BitsPerSample = 2;
            const int BufferSamples = 16;
            const int BufferSize = 4096; //same as max buffer for iOS and Android        

    protected override void OpenMediaAsync()
            {
                int byteRate = sampleRate * ChannelCount * BitsPerSample / 8;
                Debug.WriteLine("ByteRate: "+byteRate);
                short blockAlign = (short)(ChannelCount * (BitsPerSample / 8));

                 //Build string-based wave-format structure
                string waveFormat = "";
                waveFormat += ToLittleEndianString(string.Format("{0:X4}", 1));      // indicates PCM
                waveFormat += ToLittleEndianString(string.Format("{0:X4}", ChannelCount));
                waveFormat += ToLittleEndianString(string.Format("{0:X8}", sampleRate));
                waveFormat += ToLittleEndianString(string.Format("{0:X8}", byteRate));
                waveFormat += ToLittleEndianString(string.Format("{0:X4}", blockAlign));
                waveFormat += ToLittleEndianString(string.Format("{0:X4}", BitsPerSample));
                waveFormat += ToLittleEndianString(string.Format("{0:X4}", 0));

                // Put wave format string in media streams dictionary
                var mediaStreamAttributes = new Dictionary<MediaStreamAttributeKeys, string>();
                mediaStreamAttributes[MediaStreamAttributeKeys.CodecPrivateData] = waveFormat;

                // Make description to add to available streams list
                var availableMediaStreams = new List<MediaStreamDescription>();
                mediaStreamDescription = new MediaStreamDescription(MediaStreamType.Audio, mediaStreamAttributes);
                availableMediaStreams.Add(mediaStreamDescription);

                // Set some appropriate keys in the media source dictionary
                var mediaSourceAttributes = new Dictionary<MediaSourceAttributesKeys, string>();
                mediaSourceAttributes[MediaSourceAttributesKeys.Duration] = "0";
                mediaSourceAttributes[MediaSourceAttributesKeys.CanSeek] = "false";

                // Signal that the open operation is completed


   ReportOpenMediaCompleted(mediaSourceAttributes, availableMediaStreams);
        }
```

I was trying set it similar to iOS/Android which is setted like this

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
    audioFormat.mSampleRate         = 44100.00;
    audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 2;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 2;
```

I hope that update will shed some light.